# play framework gel list from Cache

Tags: caching, playframework

Through controller I send to Cache a java list List

```
@for(index <- play.api.cache.Cache.get("nrOfmessages")){
<h1>@index</h1>
}
```

I see my item in list but I dont know how to iterate over this list from cache and how to fetch this list

Also I heard thar Cahche is not a good place for storing information, but i need some place to deliver information to my template...Unfortunately I cannot use session cause session has only 4kb size and i need something more :) Maybe sombody know how to transfer this sort of data to my template better? :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use cache to store data because cache not remain all time you may get null values.

From [Play Docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.2/cache)

> It is important to understand that the cache contract is clear: when
>   you put data in a cache, you can’t expect that data to remain there
>   forever. In fact you shouldn’t. A cache is fast, but values expire,
>   and the cache generally exists only in memory (without persistent
>   backup)

From [Similar Stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732351/using-cache-in-play-framework)

> Play is stateless, you should not use the Cache as a data store. If
>   you are load balancing, there is no guarantee that you will return to
>   the same server. By keeping things in memory, you are breaking the
>   stateless nature of Play. The cache is best used when data already
>   exists in the database, but is being used to minimise frequent
>   database reads

**Solution 1:Pass List to your view**

In your *controller*

```
public static Result index() {
        List<String> message= new ArrayList<String>(); 
        message.add("message1");
        message.add("message2");
        message.add("message3");
        return ok(index.render(message));
    }
```

In your *view*

```
@(messages:List[String])

@main("index"){

@for(msg <- messages){
<div>@msg</div>
}

}
```

And you can always take help from [sample projects](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Samples) provided by play which is in the zip file that you downloaded and extracted.

> Note: You can pass variable from controller to your view in play by passing the
>   variable like you pass variable between functions in java.

**Solution 2:Directly call the models function**

In your *view*

```
@for(user<- User.all()){
<div>@user.getName</div>
}
```

where User is a model and all() is a function which returns list of users.

**Solution 3:Use ajax call to get the list**

See [how to apply ajax in Play framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133059/play-2-x-how-to-make-an-ajax-request-with-a-common-button)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't pass my variable throught my template functions because I've already used it in other cases.

Comment: @Michal If you dont want to pass variables and dont want to use session then you have another option of using a ajax call and directly call model function(see my edits) .Storing variable in cache is not a good practice and Its not good for future in your project as the pages may crash.

Comment: That was fantastic hint...I totally forgot about ajax existance thx a lot :)

Comment: @Michal have you tried `solution 2`  from my answer that would be lot easier

Comment: thanks for help...
User.all() - this is a method from controller? I think I can't use it because in this case I should use reverse routing...Could you say something more ? Some example would be very helpful :d

Comment: Oh...i got it right now...I think this is connected with EBean...unfortunately in my project I've decided to use JPA instead of Ebean (bigger community)

Comment: User is a model and all() is a function in that model(you can call function from model by ModelName.functionname() same as you call function in java)   I have tried this  `solution 2` with Ebean and JPA .I dont know if it the correct way or not but it worked for me.